# Replacing every row in a matrix

Tags: r

I've got a matrix (mat1), say 100 rows and 100 columns; I want to create another matrix where every row is the same as the 1st row in mat1 (except that I want to keep the 1st col as the original values)

I've managed to do this using a loop:

```
mat2 <- mat1

for(i in 1:nrow(mat1))
{
    mat2[i,2:ncol(mat2)] <- mat1[1,2:ncol(mat1)]
}
```

this works and produces the result I expect; however, I'd have thought there should be a way to do it without a loop; I've tried:

```
mat2 <- mat1
mat2[c(2:100),2:ncol(mat2)] <- mat1[1,2:ncol(mat1)]
```

Can someone point out my error?!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the way R fills matrices, by columns. Here is a simple example that illustrates this:

```
mat1 <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
mat2 <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)

mat2[-1, -1] <- mat1[1, -1]
mat2

> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    4    4
[3,]    3    7    7
```

`mat1[1, -1]` is the vector `4,7`, which you can see that R has used to fill the bit of `mat2` column-wise. You wanted a row-wise operation.

One solution is to replicate the replacement vector as many times as is required:

```
> mat2[-1, -1] <- rep(mat1[1, -1], each = nrow(mat1)-1)
> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    4    7
[3,]    3    4    7
```

This works because the `rep()` call replicates each value in the vector when we use the `"each"` argument, instead of replicating (repeating) the vector:

```
> rep(mat1[1, -1], each = nrow(mat1)-1)
[1] 4 4 7 7
```

The default behaviour would also give the wrong answer:

```
> rep(mat1[1, -1], nrow(mat1)-1)
[1] 4 7 4 7
```

In part, the problem you are seeing is also the way R extends arguments to the appropriate length for the replacement. R actually, and silently, extended the replacement vector exactly in the way `rep(mat1[1, -1], nrow(mat1)-1)` does, which when coupled with the fill-by-column principle gave the behaviour you saw.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mat2[c(2:nrow(mat2)), 2:ncol(mat2)] <- mat1[rep.int(1,nrow(mat1)-1),2:ncol(mat1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option...

```
n = 5
mat1 = matrix(sample(n^2, n^2), n, n)

# use matrix with byrow to copy 1st row n times
mat2 = matrix(rep(mat1[1, ], n), n, n, byrow = TRUE)

# copy 1st column 
mat2[ , 1] = mat1[ , 1]

mat1
mat2
```